# LINQ lambda expression, finding a child object where property is == X

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Need help with a LINQ lambda expression in C#.

So let me explain the structure of my object.

RootObject is a collection(custom class with multiple properties) that has many properties one of them is `List<Item>` items.
Item contains a `List<Round>` Rounds.
Round contains a `EntryRID`(this ID is unique) and `name`.

```
string = IDToFind = "111"; //The ID i want a Round object for
```

So from my List of "items" i need to find the Round ID that matches a given ID(IDToFind).
AKA i need to search every singe Item in "items" for a Round object with a ID matching IDToFind.

I've tired this expression:

```
Round playerRound = RootObject.Select(i => i.Items.Select(x => x.Rounds.Where(y => y.EntryRID == Int32.Parse(IDToFind))));
```

but its not return any kind of object, its returning:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Leaderboards,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Round]]]
```

Comment: Well yes, you've created a query - you need to iterate over the results... or use `First()`, `Single()` or whatever to get a single result. You might also want to use `SelectMany` to flatten the results... It doesn't help that it's not obvious what result type you're looking for.

Comment: Well i did explain it with text:), but now i added the Object I'm looking for(see updated post, expression)

Comment: Well what do you want to do if there are multiple matches?

Comment: there cant be as the ID of a Round is 100% unique.

Comment: you can see about [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user2408952: But that doesn't stop there being multiple references to the same Round instance in the list. Basically, you *will* need to decide between First, FirstOrDefault etc.

Comment: It's also unclear what your type of `RootObject` is - it looks like `RootObject.Items` isn't valid, but `RootObject` itself is a collection of something with an `Items` property.

Comment: yes Jon Skeet, your right. updating post right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s for each `RootObject` element. This is because your query produces an `IEnumerable` for each item of `RootObject`, and makes the result an `IEnumerable` as well.

If you would like to flatten the results into a single list, use `SelectMany`, like this:

```
var matchingItems = RootObject.SelectMany(i => i.Items.SelectMany(x => x.Rounds.Where(y => y.EntryRID == Int32.Parse(IDToFind))));
```

The above produces a collection that you can iterate:

```
foreach (var item in matchingItems) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i forgot to mention that RootObject is also a collection with many properties one of them being the List<Item> items. If you update your answer ill gladly try it again. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @user2408952 It was my assumption that `RootObject` is a collection of objects - that's why you can do a `SelectMany` on it. I missed the fact that `Rounds` needs to be flattened as well.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
// Parse the target ID *once* rather than all the time...
var targetId = int.Parse(IDToFind);
var playerRound = RootObject.SelectMany(i => i.Items)
                            .SelectMany(x => x.Rounds)
                            .Where(round => round.EntryRID == targetId)
                            .First();
```

That will return *first* matching `Round`, or throw an exception if there aren't any. You could use `FirstOrDefault` which will return `null` if there are no matching objects, or perhaps `Single()` which will make sure there's *exactly* one result.

As a query expression, you can write the above as:

```
var targetId = int.Parse(IDToFind);
var playerRound = (from foo in RootObject // You haven't told us this type
                   from item in foo.Items
                   from round in item.Rounds
                   where round.EntryRID == targetId
                   select round).First();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i forgot to mention that RootObject is also a collection with many properties one of them being the List<Item> items. If you update your answer ill gladly try it again. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @user2408952: My answer already handles that - but your description isn't quite right; the collection doesn't have an `Items` property, it's *each element* of the collection that has the property. This kind of thing is precisely why it's better to use code to demonstrate the problem rather than just a description...

Comment: yeah and i would have posted the code if it wasn't because my RootObject's properties is constructed by 300 lines of code. So i assumed no one with bother to read all 300 lines, therefor i tried to simplify it (which it seems like i failed to do).

Comment: @user2408952: Simplifying is good - but you can still do that *in code*. Being able to create a short but complete example demonstrating a problem is an important skill :)

Answer (score 1):

The result you get is an iterator, i.e. if you use it in a for loop you can iterate over the single elements, like:

```
var element = RootObject.Select(i => i.Items.Select(x => x.Rounds.Where(y => y.EntryRID == Int32.Parse(IDToFind))));
for (var element in elements)
{ // do something with the element...}
```

If you want to see the whole list immediately, you can also use the `ToList()` method which gets all elements for you and puts them into a `List`.

```
var list = element.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i forgot to mention that RootObject is also a collection with many properties one of them being the List<Item> items. If you update your answer ill gladly try it again. Sorry for the mistake.